# 2.2 upgrage to 2.2.1 issue

Tags: upgrade, magento2.2

#### Preconditions

php7.1

#### Steps to reproduce

1. I don't know why i in admin > setup upgradd >Update application is running ->will be show error upgrade. Did't suggest anything wrong?

#### Expected result

1. How to solve this issue?

#### Actual result

1. Update application is not running

Error in Update!
Please refer to documentation Doc link to perform manual rollback.

To attempt automatic rollback, please click the "Rollback" button.

```
[Module 'Magento_******':
Running schema recurring...Source class "\SignifydAvsDefault" for "SignifydAvsDefaultMapper" generation does not exist.

[2017-11-10 11:19:32 UTC] Job "setup:upgrade {"command":"setup:upgrade"}" has been successfully completed
[2017-11-10 11:19:32 UTC] Job "setup:static:regenerate []" has started

[2017-11-10 11:19:32 UTC] Cleaning generated files...
[2017-11-10 11:19:32 UTC] Clearing cache...
[2017-11-10 11:20:12 UTC] Cleaning static view files
[2017-11-10 11:20:12 UTC] Job "setup:static:regenerate []" has been successfully completed
[2017-11-10 11:20:12 UTC] Job "setup:maintenance:disable []" has started
Disabled maintenance mode

[2017-11-10 11:20:12 UTC] Job "setup:maintenance:disable []" has been successfully completed
```

Comment: Do you have more info on this error? Is it still happening? I don't understand why PHP7.1 is a pre-condition.  Does it work with 7.0?